# Python 3.6x how to export pandas data frame with € in UTF-8

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, utf-8, export

I have the problem that when I export a data frame with a column containing € to a CSV file with:

```
grouped_df.to_csv('total_five_cost_vector.csv',sep=';',encoding='utf8',index=False, float_format='%.2f')
```

Here is an example data frame:

```
cost    currency
37830.00    €
56850.00    €
```

I get 0x80 insteads of the € sign. When i want to read that file again with

```
grouped_df= pd.from_csv('total_five_cost_vector.csv',sep=';',encoding='utf8',float_format='%.2f')
```

i get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Edit: i had a typo 'endocing' instead of 'encoding', sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I can see `endocing='utf8'`. Shouldn't that spell _enCODing_?

Comment: bloody hell! my bad, thank you a lot for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

ForceBru gave me the right correction to my typo.